# Why is my segno vcard QR code causing Unfortunately Dialer has stopped error when adding its details to contacts?

Tags: python

I have created a vcard QR code with the segno library, when i add 2 fields namely (organization and title) to the helpers.make_vcard tuple that takes the vcard details the generated QR code does not save the details to the mobile phone after scanning when a user clicks add to contacts, i only get a message that says “Unfortunately dialer has stopped” but without these 2 fields (organization and title) the details are added correctly. What could be causing this? How can i fix it?

I have tried scanning with variable mobile phones thinking it is a compatibility issue but nothing is happening. When i remove the fields the details get saved upon scanning, when add them the vcard details dont get saved.

```
from segno import helpers
from PIL import Image
import datetime

qr=helpers.make_vcard(name='surname;name', displayname='Name Surname',
org='Place of work', title='Position',
phone=('71******', '77******'),email=('******@gmail.com'),
url=['http://********.com'], pobox='PO Box ***********', city='G*****')
qr.save('person.png', scale=15, background='white', color='black')
```

I expect that after reading the QR code when it says add to contacts all the necessary fields in the mobile phone should be porpulated by the details in the vcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segno supports only (a subset of) the vCard 3.0 standard, see https://segno.readthedocs.io/en/stable/special-qrcode-factories.html#vcard and https://segno.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#segno.helpers.make_vcard

Running your code:

```
>>> import segno
>>> segno.__version__
'0.3.2'
>>> from segno import helpers
>>> # Simplified your code, makes no difference, though
>>> qr = helpers.make_vcard(name='surname;name', displayname='Name Surname',
org='Place of work', title='Position',
phone=('71******', '77******'), email='******@gmail.com',
url='http://********.com', pobox='PO Box ***********', city='G*****')
>>> qr.save('person.png', scale=15)  # background='white' and color='black' are the defaults
```

results into:

[QR Code encoding a vCard 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ndbS.png)

The vCard is accepted by iOS 12.4, there seems to be no problem add it to the Contacts app.

If you encounter problems, you should create an issue to the project's bug tracker https://github.com/heuer/segno/issues and provide more information (i.e. which QR code reader do you use, which operating system ...)